# Nested class pointer access

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++11

i am rather new to c++ and in my attempt to create a linked list i have run into an error which i do not understand.

the code:

```
    template <typename T>
class List{
    class Node{
            T data;
        Node<T> *next;
        Node<T> *previous;

        Node<T>(T& data,const Node<T> *next,const Node<T> *previous): data(data),
                    next(next),previous(previous){
            };
            };
    Node<T> *head;
    Node<T> *tail;
    int size;
public:
    class Iterator{
            Node<T> *node;
            List<T> *list;
             };
    void List<T>::remove(List<T>::Iterator& It){
        if(It.list!=this){ // FIELD list COULD NOT BE RESOLVED
            throw NON_MATCHING_LIST();
        }
        if(size==0 || It.node=tail){ //FIELD node COULD NOT BE RESOLVED
            throw ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND();
        }
        It.node->previous=It.node->next; //FIELD node COULD NOT BE RESOLVED (and naturally the rest).
        It.node->next->previous=It.node->previous
    }
```

};

in my remove function, i am trying to remove the member of the list that came right before the iterator, alas i am getting an error saying

> node/list fields could not be resolved

i have tried passing the iterator as type Iterator& or Iterator, neither have worked.

Would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Not sure if it is the only issue, but you need some `typename`s, e.g.: `typename List<T>::Iterator`

Comment: `Node` is not a class template. Just say `Node`, not `Node<T>`. `List` is a template, so say `List<T>::Node`.

Comment: this actually solved it, thanks. Andy if you repost as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Also, do not qualify member function declarations with the class name inside a class (i.e. say `void remove(...)`, not `void List<T>::remove(...)`.

Comment: Also, `It.node=tail` should probably be `It.node==tail` ;)

Comment: I recommend that you examine `remove` carefully. Draw what happens using pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from issues that others have mentioned in the comments to the question, it seems your (first) problem is that you need to use the `typename` disambiguator:

```
    typename List<T>::Iterator
//  ^^^^^^^^
```

This tells the compiler that it should parse `Iterator` as the name of a *type*, rather than the name of a data member of `List<T>`.